# Does PostgreSQL know properly about daylight saving time?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

Comparing a calculation of timestamps there is a difference based on when it happened:

```
hj=# set time zone 'Europe/Berlin';
SET
hj=# select '1991-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01', '1991-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01'::timestamp with time zone - '2 months'::interval;
           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 1991-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01 | 1991-09-30 07:25:38.235095+01

hj=# select '2010-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01', '2010-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01'::timestamp with time zone - '2 months'::interval;
           ?column?            |           ?column?            
-------------------------------+-------------------------------
 2010-11-30 07:25:38.235095+01 | 2010-09-30 07:25:38.235095+02
```

Actually, daylight saving time was introduced in 1980 and not changed up to now. So in both cases - whether 2010 or 1991 - it should show a '+02' at the end of the result, because in September, daylight saving time was effective.

Comment: According to this https://www.timeanddate.de/stadt/zeitumstellung/deutschland?year=1991 the result is correct. on 1991-09-30 "Winterzeit" was active

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That's exactly what I did.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, I didn't know that DST ended earlier in some years (compared to now). Thanks! (But somehow I figured that PostgreSQL was correct)